# How do deploy a virtual machine using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine, infrastructure-as-code

I’m new to Ansible. I can create one VM using Ansible. I’d like to deploy multiple VMs at one go. I’d appreciate any references or guidelines to accomplish this.

Comment: `I can create one Vm using Ansible` => where is the playbook doing that ? What did you try to make it usable for several vms ? Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through the [cloud modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html).

Which module applies to you depends on your infrastructure provider (i.e. vsphere, aws, gcp, libvirt, etc)

For example:

- [virt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/virt_module.html#virt-module) for libvirt
- [cloudformation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudformation_module.html#cloudformation-module) for aws
- [vsphere_guest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vsphere_guest_module.html#vsphere-guest-module) for vsphere
- [azure_rm_deployment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_deployment_module.html#azure-rm-deployment-module) for azure
- ...and many more

There are also tons of community developed roles at [ansible-galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) if the above don't quite meet your use case.